# Targeting classes within popovers 'data-content' using .on()

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

as you can see below. I'm triggering this particular popover through a span element and populating it using data-content.

```
<span class="selectYear addCursor" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-title="Available Years" data-content="<a href='#' class='executeYearChange'>2013</a> | <a href='#' class='executeYearChange'>2014</a> | <a href='#' class='executeYearChange'>2015</a>">Change Year</span>
```

Heres my jquery which is supposed to modify the year displayed on a few other classes

```
$(function(){
            $('.selectYear').on('click','.executeYearChange', function(){
                var newYear = $(this).text();
                globalYear = newYear;
                $(".globalYearDisplay").text('Current Selected Year: ' + globalYear);
                console.log(newYear, 'Test');
            });
        });
```

I thought I was binding my click event to the right place (the span element class) but I am not getting a response in the page or in the console, nor does the .globalYearDisplay change at all.

Obviously my function cannot see the `.executeYearChange` class so is there a trick to attaching it correctly? I thought having a delegated function .on() used in this manner would cover the fact that it is not visible to the DOM at page load.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it `selectYear ` or `yearSelect`?

Comment: it is selectYear, fixed it in the OP. I thought that might have been the problem but I am still having the same issue described above.

Comment: @GabrielNegut When you click "Change Year" it triggers the popover which is titled "Available Years" and has the links : 2013 | 2014 | 2015 as the popover-content. The <a> tags are not children of the span because I don't want them to be there before the user triggers the popover. Otherwise what would be the point of having it as a popover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your selector. The popover is attached to the span tag, but is not a child of it, so the event won't bubble up the way you want it to.  Instead, listen for clicks on the body tag that match the element you are targeting.  Try:

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('click','.executeYearChange', function(){
            var newYear = $(this).text();
            globalYear = newYear;
            $(".globalYearDisplay").text('Current Selected Year: ' + globalYear);
            console.log(newYear, 'Test');
        });
    });
```